# Possible to configure rails to load per project .irbrc file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb, rails-console

Can rails load `.irbrc` from the rails project root such as `~/rails-projct/.irbrc`. Rather then `~/.irbrc`. Since it would be nice to add configuration that's specific to a project.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Configuration):

> IRB reads from ~/.irbrc when it's invoked.
> If ~/.irbrc doesn't exist, irb will try to read in the following order:
>
> - .irbrc
> - irb.rc
> - _irbrc
> - $irbrc

Meaning that this is possible, but only if you *don't* have a `.irbrc` file in your home directory. Tested and confirmed in Ruby 2.7.

If that's not possible, you'll have to rely on command line options and/or environment variables.